# How to set custom flash with respond_to in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, respond-to

In `respond_to` you can set `flash[:notice]` like this

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html { redirect_to photo_path(photo), :notice => 'The photos was saved') }
  format.xml  { render :xml => photo, :status => :created}
end
```

I am trying to set flash[:success] with `:success => "yay"` but it doesn't work.

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should use redirect_to differently :

```
redirect_to photo_path(photo), :flash => { :success => "Yeepee!" }
```

The only flashes you can use directly are

- :notice
- :alert
- :error

Hope that helps

Answer (score 5):

From Rails 4, you can directly use `:success` in `redirect_to`.

Just add this line:

```
# in app/controllers/application_controller.rb

class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
    [...]

    add_flash_types :error, :success, :info

    [...]
```

Without this line, in respond_to, :notice produces flash, but :success doesn't work.

Hat tip to [Milan Mondal's post for this](https://coderwall.com/p/-2klvg/custom-flash-helper-in-rails4)!